# Animating a SwiftUI view with UIView.animate

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, uiview, uikit

I've noticed that `UIView.animate` is less quirky and 'smoother' with less lag than using `withAnimation { }` and the general Animation class in SwiftUI. That being said, I have some `Flashcards` that I'm flipping. The problem is, when I use `withAnimation { }`, there's some lag that sometimes makes it look like the card isn't even flipping (it looks like just the content inside the card instantly changes). I have 5 flashcards in a ScrollView rendered at the same time. How can I use `UIView.animate()` to animate the change?

```
struct Flashcard<Front, Back>: View where Front: View, Back: View {
    var front: () -> Front
    var back: () -> Back
    
    @State var flipped: Bool = false
    
    @State var flashcardRotation = 0.0
    @State var contentRotation = 0.0
    
    init(@ViewBuilder front: @escaping () -> Front, @ViewBuilder back: @escaping () -> Back) {
        self.front = front
        self.back = back
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if flipped {
                ZStack {
                    back()
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                flipFlashcard()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Flipper")
                            }).padding(5)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ZStack {
                    front()
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                flipFlashcard()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Flipper")
                            }).padding(5)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(contentRotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        .frame(height: 150)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(flashcardRotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    }
    
    func flipFlashcard() {
        let animationTime = 0.25
//        My attempt at using UIView.animate()
//        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: {
//            flashcardRotation += 180
//        })

        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: animationTime)) {
            flashcardRotation += 180
        }

//        My attempt at using UIView.animate()
//        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.001, delay: animationTime / 2, animations: {
//            contentRotation += 180
//            flipped.toggle()
//        }, completion: nil)
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.001).delay(animationTime / 2)) {
            contentRotation += 180
            flipped.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a `UIViewRepresentable` and a `ViewModifier` to make it user friendly.

This is done by affecting the `UIView` version of your SwiftUI `View` as a whole. You wouldn't be changing variables within the SwiftUI `View`.

The `UIViewRepresentable` is to make SwiftUI compatible with UIKit

```
struct FlipWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable{
    //The content to be flipped
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    //Triggers the animation
    @Binding var flip: Bool
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        //Convert SwiftUI View to UIKit UIView
        UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        //Variable must be used somewhere or it wont trigger
        print(flip)
        //Transition is a much easier way to Flip in UIKit
        UIView.transition(with: uiView, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then to make it easy to use, put the wrapper in a `ViewModifier` so it can be accessed like all the other modifiers

```
extension View {
    func flipAnimation( flipped: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        modifier(FlipAnimationViewModifier(flipped: flipped))
    }
}
struct FlipAnimationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var flipped: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        FlipWrapper(content: {
            content
        }, flip: $flipped)
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier

Now to use it just access

```
.flipAnimation(flipped: Binding<Bool>)
```

Attached to the `View` you want to flip when the variable is changed.

Sample use would be like below. In `Flashcard` you will `flipped.toggle()` instead of calling `flipFlashcard()`

```
struct Flashcard<Front, Back>: View where Front: View, Back: View {
    @ViewBuilder var front: () -> Front
    @ViewBuilder var back: () -> Back
    
    @State var flipped: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if flipped{
                back()
            }else{
                front()
            }
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        flipped.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Flipper")
                    }).padding(5)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.flipAnimation(flipped: $flipped)
            .frame(height: 150)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

If you want to "fancy" it up a little more you can pass the transition/animation parameters up to SwiftUI for values.

```
extension View {
    func flipAnimation(flipped: Binding<Bool>, duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionFlipFromRight, animationConfiguration: ((UIView) -> Void)? = nil, onComplete: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)-> some View {
        modifier(FlipAnimationViewModifier(flipped: flipped, duration: duration, options: options, animationConfiguration: animationConfiguration, onComplete: onComplete))
    }
}
struct FlipAnimationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var flipped: Bool
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var options: UIView.AnimationOptions
    var animationConfiguration: ((UIView) -> Void)?
    var onComplete: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        FlipWrapper(content: {
            content
        }, flip: $flipped, duration: duration, options: options, animationConfiguration: animationConfiguration, onComplete: onComplete)
    }
}
struct FlipWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable{
    //The content to be flipped
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    //Triggers the animation
    @Binding var flip: Bool
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var options: UIView.AnimationOptions
    var animationConfiguration: ((UIView) -> Void)?
    var onComplete: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        //Convert SwiftUI View to UIKit UIView
        UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        //Vaariable must be used somewhere or it wont trigger
        print(flip)
        //update gets called after make, if you only want to trigger the animation when you change flip you have to lock it for the first time
        //using the corrdinator to store the state makes it easy
        if !context.coordinator.initAnim{
            //Transition is a much simpler way to flip using UIKit
            UIView.transition(with: uiView, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {
                if animationConfiguration != nil{
                    animationConfiguration!(uiView)
                }
            }, completion: onComplete)
        }else{
            context.coordinator.initAnim = false
        }
    }
    class Coordinator{
        //Variable to lock animation for initial run
        var initAnim: Bool = true
        var parent: FlipWrapper
        init(_ parent:FlipWrapper){
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add different configuration changes to the `UIView` so they can be done as `animations`

```
.flipAnimation(flipped: $flipped, animationConfiguration: {
    view in
    view.alpha = Double.random(in: 0.25...1)
    view.backgroundColor = [.red,.gray,.green].randomElement()!
})
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: Hmm. on macOS 11.6.2, using CABasicAnimation (since there is no UIView.transition) works, but SwiftUI draws the back side and then calls `updateNSView` for the `FlipWrapper` rather than switching the view half way through the animation like it does on iOS.   Tried wrapping the call to do the actual animation in both `withAnimation(context.transaction.animation) { rotateView(for: nsView)` and `withTransaction(context.transaction) { rotateView(for: nsView)` but neither solved the issue.  Any ideas?  Code: https://gist.github.com/GeekAndDadDad/d5bb863c0b5b41d458eed2865c98740c

Comment: I can see potentially doing it by triggering the animation on `subviews` changing and using NSViewRepresentables for the card views but… ugh.

Comment: @Dad all those little intricacies is why I used `transition`, animation is a lot more work. You just have to create the details yourself since you can't use the apple provided. use`.opacity` instead of the `if else` to hide and make minor adjustments to make it look pretty.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunate that `transition` isn't available on macOS.  I had already tried `.opacity` instead of if/else but haven't gotten that quite the way I'd like.  animating that change just the right way might be sufficient so playing with that next :). cheers!

Comment: This example has some amazing stuff, including a SwiftUI flip animation via a custom GeometryEffect:  https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part2/

Comment: @Dad Are you trying to use it for something specific or just playing? I've been playing with it a little, kind of a slow day for me. I have the spinning looking semi decent but if you increase the time you will see that there is a correction in the very last frame to correct the fact that it is facing the opposite way. That is my biggest issue to get it looking decent in the macOS version

Comment: Just playing/learning :).  I know that little offset and resizing the window a small amount fixed it for me.  I was guessing non-integral pixel alignment during animation or something like that.   I'm also a bit skeptical of the OP's issue doing this with SwiftUI - as I said in my (now deleted) answer, it seems possible to make this very performant using SwiftUI built-in stuff. The custom GeometryEffect in that the SwifUI-Lab link I posted above, for example. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Dad as I typed that last message I figured it out. Add a 3rd layer to the `ZStack` that is `Color.grey` `onChange` of `flipped` do a linear animation to changes the opacity of the color to 1 and at the end of the duration of the animation switch it back to 0. At first glance I don't see the different between the transition and the animation. Also divide by -1000 vs -200

Comment: @Dad I play around with UIKit animation and SwiftUI views every once its a while. I make this pretty cool bubble animation a while ago that I could not figure out in SwiftUI.

Comment: :) I have something along those lines - the third view - sketched out also but got pulled away for some work so haven't finished it.  Looking at the UIKit one you did with `transition` you can see that the front view fades towards dark gray and then fades back up to the new one so that's what made me think to try something similar.

Comment: (Looking at `Animation.timingCurve` to get timing looking right for third view approach,  but `Animatable` protocol also looks interesting. :) ).

Comment: Once we're animating so much in SwiftUI (the third view) it seems like it makes more sense to just use SwiftUI animation for everything (which was effectively my answer to the OP's question that I deleted). Just have to learn how to make them performant enough. I would have liked to know more on OP's context (simulator? on device? etc) and when they saw the pause. Anyway, fun stuff!