# Swift UI - Using UIVIewControllerRepresentable to update logs

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The logic I'm trying to create for my logging in the app is:

1. A ScrollView with a frame to control the height and allow the user to see logs from actions in the app, the logs should be scrollable to scroll up on previous appended logs.
2. I've created a log view model which allows the log to be set and then appends to a log array and then get.
3. The logs are set through actions in callbacks from various view controllers and actions from the user.
4. currently I have the logs being retrieved in the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` - `updateUIViewController` method.
5. The code works for each callback and for the user actions, the problems are: 5a. It's not scrollable to go to the top of the log messages, 5b. The log messages keep showing on the screen as `updateUIViewController` is continuously being called.

I was trying to think of a way to empty the array after each action, but not sure the best way to go about this.

Code:

LogViewModel:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class LogViewModel: ObservableObject{
        
    @Published var mTime: String = ""
    @Published var id: String = "#"
    @Published var mMessage: String = ""
    private var fullLogMessages: [String] = [""]
    
    func setTimeFormatter() -> DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
           return formatter
    }
    
    func setTheTime(date: Date){
        self.mTime = setTimeFormatter().string(from: date)
    }
    
    func getTheTime() -> String{
        return self.mTime
    }
    
    func setTheMessage(mMessage: String) {
        ThreadUtil.runAsyncOnMainThread { [weak self] in
            self?.mMessage = mMessage
        }
    }
    
    func getTheMessage() -> String {
        return self.mMessage
    }
    
    func getTheFullLogMessage() -> [String] {
        let fullLog: String = getTheTime() + " - " + getTheGivenId() + " - " + getTheMessage()
        self.fullLogMessages.append(fullLog)
        return self.fullLogMessages
    }
    
    func setTheGivenId(id: String) {
        ThreadUtil.runAsyncOnMainThread { [weak self] in
            self?.id = id
        }
    }
    
    func getTheGivenId() -> String {
        return self.id
    }
}
```

Controllers:
In each controller I've created a method like this to set the log messages:

```
 func setTheLogMessages(message: String) {
        self.logViewModel.setTheTime(date: date)
        self.logViewModel.setTheMessage(mMessage: message)
    }
```

In the view I have the UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
struct MyScreenView_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: myScreenViewModel
    @ObservedObject var logViewModel: LogViewModel
    @Binding var fullLogMessage: [String]
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some myViewController {
        print(#function)
        return myViewController(viewModel: viewModel, logViewModel: logViewModel)
    }
   
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        print(#function)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() +  0.5) {
            fullLogMessage = logViewModel.getTheFullLogMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

and the ScrollView for the UI:

```
    ScrollView{
        VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
        Text("Logs")
            .font(.footnote).fontWeight(.medium)
        ForEach($fullLogMessage, id: \.self) { $logMessage in
            Text(logMessage)
                .font(.custom("FONT_NAME", size: 12))
                .disabled(true)
            }
          })
            .frame(width: 400, height: 50,  alignment: .leading)
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, I asked the question you posted and it helped me previously. I was now implementing logging in the same way and it works, issue I have is once a log gets appended it doesn't stop updating as you can see I have it in the updateUIViewController. Need it to be more robust, scrollable and only have the single output of log messages at a time.

Comment: Don't do stuff in `updateUIViewController` unless you have checks so stuff doesn't get called unnecessarily. You can set it in `makeUIViewController` and then call it on purpose with the methods when you need it. Your code isn't reproducible so I can't give you more than that. I can't see the whole picture.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553786/animating-a-swiftui-view-with-uiview-animate/70645853#70645853) answer you will see a check in the `update` method in the second option.

Comment: Also consider another approach. I usually have a `LogManager` that everything and anything accesses the `class` whenever it wants. I have a `Notification` that gets posted when there is an error and a `ViewModel` at the top level subscribes to it and posts and `Alert` for me, sometimes I don't even know where the error comes from. You can easily maintain the log in the one `class` and make it visible. It is really seamless. Its is kind of an MVC setup because I use services to incorporate crashlytics and I have a system service the decides between Logger and osLog based on version

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum this LogManager sounds similar to the LogViewModel I have added in my question. I return the getTheFullLogMessage() to get the array of logs appended. What I need is a way to call getTheFullLogMessage() so it updates on the View with the last element of the array each time within the ScrollView I have shown above.

Comment: The advantage of using a Notification like @loremipsum suggests is that it keeps the code holding messages and the scrollview (and UI in general) separate. Also, does it need to be a UIViewControllerRepresentable, why not just a swiftUI scrollview?

Comment: I did not understand your issue. Do you need a scrollable logs list? So what is the purpose of the `MyScreenView_UI` ?  did you consider using `ObservableObject` inside the SwiftUI view directly? So no need for `getTheFullLogMessage` at all

Comment: @Sam did you look at the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but here is a simplified version of what seems to be what you are trying to do.

First, add a `LogManager` that can be created by **ANY** `class` or `struct`

```
struct LogManager{
    var name: String
    ///Simplified post that takes in the String and uses the name as the source
    func postMessage(message: String){
        postMessage(message: .init(timestamp: Date(), message: message, source: name))
    }
    //MARK: Notification
    ///Sends a Notification with the provided message
    func postMessage(message: Message){
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .logManagerMessage, object: message)
    }
    ///Adds an observer to the manager's notification
    func observeMessageNotification(observer: Any, selector: Selector){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer, selector: selector, name: .logManagerMessage, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Put at `class` or `struct` level the declaration for the manager

```
private let log = LogManager(name: "YourClassStructName")
```

Then call

```
log.postMessage(message: "your message here")
```

When you want to log a message.

In the ViewModel you would

1. subscribe to the notifications
2. maintain the array

Like below

```
class AppLogSampleViewModel: ObservableObject{
    static let shared: AppLogSampleViewModel = .init()
    private let manager = LogManager(name: "AppLogSampleViewModel")
    @Published var messages: [Message] = []
    private init(){
        //Observe the manager's notification
        manager.observeMessageNotification(observer: self, selector: #selector(postMessage(notification:)))
    }
    ///Puts the messages received into the array
    @objc
    func postMessage(notification: Notification){
        if notification.object is Message{
            messages.append(notification.object as! Message)
        }else{
            messages.append(.init(timestamp: Date(), message: "Notification received did not have message", source: "AppLogSampleViewModel :: \(#function)"))
        }
    }
}
```

If your `View` won't be at the highest level you need to call.

```
let startListening: AppLogSampleViewModel = .shared
```

In the `ContentView` or `AppDelegate` so the `ViewModel` starts listening as quickly as possible. You won't necessarily use it for anything but it needs to be called as soon as you want it to start logging messages.

Only the `View` that shows the messages uses the instance of the `ViewModel`.

```
struct AppLogSampleView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: AppLogSampleViewModel = .shared
    //Create this variable anywhere in your app
    private let log = LogManager(name: "AppLogSampleView")
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Button("post", action: {
                //Post like this anywhere in your app
                log.postMessage(message: "random from button")
            })
            DisclosureGroup("log messages"){
                ForEach(vm.messages, content: { message in
                    VStack{
                        Text(message.timestamp.description)
                        Text(message.message)
                        Text(message.source)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code you need to get this sample working.

```
struct AppLogSampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AppLogSampleView()
    }
}
extension Notification.Name {
    static let logManagerMessage = Notification.Name("logManagerMessage")
}
struct Message: Identifiable{
    let id: UUID = .init()
    var timestamp: Date
    var message: String
    var source: String
}
```

Only the one `View` that shows the messages needs access to the `ViewModel` and only one `ViewModel` subscribes to the notifications.

All the other classes and structs will just create an instance of the manager and call the method to post the messages.

There is no sharing/passing between the classes and structs everybody gets their own instance.

Your manager can have as many or as little methods as you want, mine usually mimics the `Logger` from `osLog` with `log`, `info`, `debug` and  `error` methods.

The specific methods call the `osLog` and `3rd party Analytics` `Services` corresponding methods.

Also, the `error` method sends a notification that a `ViewModel` at the top level receives and shows an `Alert`.

To get all this detail working it takes a lot more code but you have the pattern with the code above.

In your code, in the `updateUIViewController` you break the single source if truth rule by copying the messages and putting them in another source of truth, right here.

```
fullLogMessage = logViewModel.getTheFullLogMessage()
```

This is also done without a check to make sure that you don't go into an infinite loop. Anytime there is code in an `update` method you should check that the work actually needs to be done. Such as comparing that the new location doesn't already match the old location.

Comment: Sorry was away and just got back. Thank you for your answer, very appreciated. Few things, I've added the LogManager and I'm getting a few errors showing 1) .init 'no exact matches in call to initialiser'  2) Cannot find Message in scope 3) Type NSNotification.Name has no member .logManagerMessage. Also in the view where I have DisclosureGroup there's an error showing 'generic parameter Content could not be inferred with

Comment: Actually my bad think I missed the last bit. Just testing it now

Comment: Sorry for thr delay, been quite busy. It works. Only additional thing I would add in the view is the on Change to scroll to the last added log. Thank you

Comment: @Sam No problem kind of a waste that the bounty expired. you can `vm.messages.reversed()` in the loop or [ScrollViewReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader) to implement the scrolling `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you made it very complicated. Let's do this with a simple approach.

#### 1. Define what is a Log

- Each log should be identifiable
- Each log should represent it's creation date
- Each log should have a message

```
struct Log: Equatable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let date = Date()
    let message: String
}
```

---

#### 2. Define where logs should be

- Changes in the logs should be observable
- Logs should be accessible in any view

```
import Combine

class LogManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var logs = [Log]()
}
```

**Note:** An `EnvironmentObject` is a good choice for such an object!

---

#### 3. Define how to show logs

```
import SwiftUI

extension Log: Identifiable { }

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var logManager: LogManager

    var body: some View {
        List(logManager.logs) { log in
            HStack {
                Text(log.message)
                Text(log.date.ISO8601Format()) // Or any format you like
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>This UI is just a simple sample and could be replaced by any other UI</sub>

**Note:** ScrollToTop is automatically enabled in the `List`

**Note:** You may want to use a singleton or injected logger because of the nature of the *logger*

**Note:** Don't forget to create and pass in the environment object