# How to use OSLog with SwiftUI?

Tags: logging, swiftui

I'm looking at adding Apple's Unified Logging to my app. Initially I just thought "Set up a logger and set it as an environment object" because it's how we do DI in SwiftUI. However `Logger` is a struct which means I cannot just apply the `ObservableObject` protocol and set it in the environment.

So I'm casting about looking for how to use it. Preferable without setting up a singleton as that just feels 'wrong'.

Has anyone tried anything like this and what did you do?

Comment: Exactly because it is a struct you don't need any singletons or something, it is just a door to logging engine - create in place/context where you need logging and put logs. If you want to have custom subsystems, just create helper extensions to construct specific Logger. To not duplicate review https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/oslog-unified-logging/ (search Logger)

Comment: Yeah, a simple approach. I tried a few things and they all got pretty messy pretty quick so although it doesn't appear to fit within the way SwiftUI would like us to work, it's probably the best technique.

Comment: I usually put the logger reference in a LogManager. That way I have a single class/struct for all the log functionality. This es especially helpful when you incorporate remote analytics. You just reference the one class. You can see the start of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864461/swift-ui-using-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable-to-update-logs/71104782#71104782)

Answer (score 0):

Example from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code):

```
let customLogger = Logger(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem", category: "your_category_name")
            
customLogger.notice("Here you want to notice smth.")
customLogger.debug("Debug message.")
```

Comment: No matter what I import, I get `'any Logger' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers` - I'm not sure why this is happening; Swift seems confused by something.