# Throwing paper animation effect in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

What would be the best animation method in `SwiftUI` to reproduce the `UIKit` animation shown below?

What I need is basically a throwing effect starting from point A and ending at Point B. I don't need any bouncing effects, this is more of an effect to let the user know that something was added from point A to Point B; similar to the effect we get when we add a photo to an album in Photos.

I tried using `.rotationEffect()` but the animation I get is too circular and with no option to add the point locations. I need a more natural `throwing-paper-like` animation where you define three points, start, apex and end, see the image below.

Any suggestions?

### What I have tried in SwiftUI that cannot make it look like a throwing paper animation.

```
struct KeyframeAnimation: View {
    @State private var ascend = false
    @State private var ascendDescend = false
    @State private var descend = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                ZStack{
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .font(.title)
                        .offset(x: -157)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(ascend ? 17: 0))
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(ascendDescend ? 145: 0))
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(descend ? 18: 0))
                        .onAppear{
                            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)){
                                self.ascend.toggle()
                            }
                            
                            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)){
                                self.ascendDescend.toggle()
                            }
                            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).delay(8)){
                                self.descend.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### UIKit Animation - Complete Working Code

This is what I need.

```
@IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
        myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: pointA.center.x - 25, y: pointA.center.y - 25, width: 50, height: 50))
        myView?.backgroundColor = .blue
        myView?.layer.cornerRadius = myView!.frame.height / 2
        view.addSubview(myView!)
    
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointA.center.x, y: self.pointA.center.y)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.9, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x + 75, y: self.pointB.center.y - 50 )
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        })
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x, y: self.pointB.center.y)
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
        })
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.myView?.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Look into `GeometryEffect` SwiftUI is not suited for combining animations with the `ViewModifier`s

Comment: I'll take a look at GeomertyEffect. Thanks.

Comment: I never thought these type of animations were that hard in SwiftUI. I have been practicing with `GeometryEffect` and it's straight forward for simple scaling or linear movements but I'm not sure how to accomplish the throwing effect with `CGAffineTransform` or `CATransform3D` which is what the `effectValue` method returns. @loremipsum - I don't need any code but based on what you know about `GeometryEffect` do you really think that I should be able to accomplish the animation with `GeometryEffect`, `CGAffineTransform` and `GeometryReader` ?

Comment: Geometry effect for sure, you don’t need geometry reader. I don’t work with animations a whole lot but I did a double heart beat animation with it, mimicking key frames (full size, small, mid, small, full size) the premise would be the same for this instead of scale like I used you are modifying  the position and size. CGAffineTransform Is a universal matrix standard where certain values change for certain animations you can find what each value means in animation tutorials, I think the documentation touches on it but it is really low level.

Comment: @loremipsum Ah ok, I'll keep practicing with `CGAffineTransform` animations.  I think the `GeometryReader` will be needed to determine the location of Point A and Point B within the screen not for the animation itself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I were to start to create this animation I would probably approach it by just getting from a to b at the desired size, in a straight line. You can likely add the curve with a basic physics equation for arc.

Comment: Also, your question says you want it  using swiftui but if that UIKit animation works you can just put it in a modifier and apply it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553786/animating-a-swiftui-view-with-uiview-animate/70645853#70645853

Comment: Wow, both of your last comments are a big help. I never thought about using my existing UIKit animation. I'll try the SwitUI way and if I can't then I'll use the UIKit animation that I already have. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up after spending a lot of time trying to do the animation in SwfitUI and ended up reusing the existing UIKit animation using a `UIViewRepresentable` as suggested in the following thread. Thank you, @ loremipsum.

[Animating a SwiftUI view with UIView.animate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553786/animating-a-swiftui-view-with-uiview-animate/70645853#70645853/)

#### Working Code by Reusing the Existing UIKit Animation

```
   import SwiftUI

    struct WrapUIKitAnimationInSwiftUI: View {
        @State private var isAnimating = false
        var body: some View {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 65))
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .throwAnimation(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isAnimating.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }


    struct ThrowAnimationWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable{
        @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
        @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
            UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view
        }
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
            if isAnimating{
                UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                        uiView.center =  CGPoint(x: 250, y: 300)
                    })
                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.9, animations: {
                        uiView.center =  CGPoint(x: 100 + 75, y: 100 - 50 )
                        uiView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
                    })
                    
                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                        uiView.center =  CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
                        uiView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2)
                    })
                }, completion: { _ in
                    uiView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    extension View {
        func throwAnimation( isAnimating: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
            modifier(ThrowAnimationViewModifier(isAnimating: isAnimating))
        }
    }
    struct ThrowAnimationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
        @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            ThrowAnimationWrapper(content: {
                content
            }, isAnimating: $isAnimating)
        }
    }
```

Comment: my god you're a god.