# How to stop view from redrawing when using scaleEffect in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple button, when you press it, It scale for a bit and then back to the first state.Using `scaleEffect` caused the view redraw and I don't want this because of the `performance`. Is There any way to prevent swiftUI from `redrawing` when using scaleEffect?

Note: (to represent the redrawing I use random background for button).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scale = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
               
                withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.68, blendDuration: 0.6)) {
                    scale.toggle()
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        scale.toggle()
                    }
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(.debug)
                    .scaleEffect(scale ? 1.1 : 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
    static var debug: Color {
    #if DEBUG
        return Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1)
        ).opacity(0.7)
    #else
        return Color(.clear)
    #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553786/animating-a-swiftui-view-with-uiview-animate/70645853#70645853

Comment: Have you tried using `transformEffect` instead of `scaleEffect`?

Comment: "redrawing"? SwiftUI doesn't draw anything, that is done in UIKit or below. SwiftUI just recomputes and diffs value types which is basically negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that `ContentView` (in this case) is being redrawn, then move the button to its own View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScalingButton()
        }
    }
}

struct ScalingButton: View {
    
    @State var scale = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
           
            withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.68, blendDuration: 0.6)) {
                scale.toggle()
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    scale.toggle()
                }
            }
            
        } label: {
            Text("Button")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(.debug)
                .scaleEffect(scale ? 1.1 : 1)
        }

    }
}
```