# SwiftUI Animation completion handler/closure

Tags: animation, swiftui, closures, tvos

is there the possibility in some way to call a handler or closure when a certain animation on a view using the animation-View-Modifier has ended?

Like the "animate" - Feature in UIKit:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate

I'm using this:

```
  .animation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDurationOffsetX), value: xOffset)
```

But as I already said there is no way to pass a completion block.

Thank you!

Best Regards,

Frank

Comment: Did you try something on your own and share some code?

Comment: I'm just using this modifier:

  .animation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDurationOffsetX), value: xOffset) 

but there is no way to pass a completion handler.

Comment: Not in SwiftUI, GeomeryEffect gives you a bit more control but you can always create a `ViewModifier` and handle the animations in UIKit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI withAnimation completion callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763709/swiftui-withanimation-completion-callback)

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: I guess implementing my own ViewModifier might be the cleanest and most concise solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553786/animating-a-swiftui-view-with-uiview-animate/70645853#70645853

Answer (score 2):

If your deployment target is at least iOS 17 (or tvOS 17, etc., released on 2023-09-18), you can use the [`addAnimationCompletion` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/transaction/addanimationcompletion(criteria:_:)) to add a completion handler to the `Transaction` associated with the animation. This works for me in Xcode 15.0 beta 1 in an iOS playground:

```
struct Demo: View {
    @State var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        (flag ? Color.red : Color.white)
            .transaction {
                $0.addAnimationCompletion {
                    print("animated")
                }
            }
            .animation(.easeOut, value: flag)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                flag.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```